# Помогите исправить ошибку в коде Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задание:

1. Определить ОДЗ для своей функции.
2. Создать DataFrame с двумя столбцами - первый вещественные числа из
   отрезка [a,b] с шагом h (отрезок берем из ОДЗ), второй столбец - значение
   функции y(x) в соответствующих точках.
3. Вывести DataFrame на экран.
4. Добавить строку со значениями точки x = b+1 и y = y(b+1).
5. Удалить первую строку.
6. Удалить строки, в которых значение x < b//2.
7. Сохранить файл в формате csv.
8. Построить средствами Python график своей функции на выбранном
   отрезке.

По нему я написал код, но у меня выходит ошибка:

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a, b = 3, 30
h = 1
n = (b-a)/h + 1
 
# 2.
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':  np.linspace(a, b, n)})
df['y'] = np.log(df.x/(df.x-2))
 
# 3.
print(df)
 
# 4.
fun = lambda elem: [elem, np.log(elem/(elem-2))]
df.loc[n] = fun(b+1)
print(df)
 
# 5.
df.drop(index=0, inplace=True)
print(df)
 
# 6.
df = df[(df.x.values > b//2) | (df.x.values == b//2)]
print(df)
 
# 7.
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, delimiter=',')
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: У вас в трейсе ошибки было указание на строку с местом, где она возникла. Не надо усложнять жизнь отвечающим  - передавайте описание ошибки полностью.

Comment: `(b-a)/h` -> `(b-a)//h`.

Comment: И в последней строке `sep=','`, вместо `delimiter`

Answer (score 3):

Число отрезков в `np.linspace(a, b, n)` должно быть целое, поэтому `n` должно быть целое, а не дробное, сделать это проще всего используя целочисленное деление `//`:

```
n = (b-a)//h + 1
```

Кроме того, у метода `.to_csv` нет параметра `delimiter`, а есть параметр `sep`:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

И похвально, конечно, что вы знаете, как комбинировать условия в `Pandas`, но он вполне понимает `>=`, два условия не нужны, можно обойтись одним условием. Кроме того, `.values` использовать не нужно, при сравнении `Series` с числом `Pandas` и так понимает, что сравнивается `values`, а не `index`:

```
df = df[df.x >= b//2]
```

P.S. Отрисовка графика делается элементарно средствами самого `Pandas`:

```
df.plot(x='x', y='y');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое, а можете помочь с 8 пунктом? у меня там просто ошибка на ошибке, сколько раз не пробовал

Comment: @RacAbyFacKush Добавил код, там элементарно

Comment: @RacAbyFacKush, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -1):

Похоже, в коде, связанном с методом, произошла ошибка. Метод pandas DataFrame не имеет параметра с именем . Вместо этого он использует для указания разделителя для CSV-файла.

Comment: `Метод pandas DataFrame не имеет параметра с именем .` - каким именем? `Вместо этого он использует для указания разделителя для CSV-файла.` - что использует?